# DNS does not resolve

Tags: dns, web-hosting, domain

I have a domain name that I have added as an add-on domain on another primary domain that I own.

I have changed the nameservers with the domain name registrar 5 days ago and a whois search shows that the nameservers have indeed changed.

However the domain is not accessible through the web browser. The browser always shows "This webpage cannot be displayed."

The problem is not with the webhost since I have many other add-on domains and all are working just fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What does a tracert show? I also think this might get better answers at serverfault

Comment: it shows "Unable to resolve target system name"

Comment: Do not use a browser to debug a DNS problem. Use dig instead. What does 'dig ANY mydomain.example.com' says?

Comment: Better to indicate the actual domain name. Otherwise, we can only guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're a command-line type of user, you could try the following commands:

1. **ipconfig /flushdns**
2. **nslookup**

Then, under this, you will get a **>** prompt. First, enter the command:

**server**

It will tell you who is your current DNS server. If this is something like 192.168.1.1 or similar, this is likely your own router. Try entering:

**server**

Retry to see whether this makes a difference. You can also try:

**server 208.67.222.222**

This is for OpenDNS. It should also be able to resolve your server IP address.

If this works, this indeed means that your domain and web site are properly registered on the net and are properly resolving for everyone. If not, contact your provider so that this gets resolved.

You then may have to flush the DNS cache of your router, if needed.

All this assumes that your website/server is hosted somewhere that is known and is setup by your provider. Usually, your web site provider is also the domain hosting provider. For myself, I use GoDaddy, and both my domains and web sites are hosted there. However, i have full control over all my domain and zone files. Your provider shouyld also be able to help you for any hosting matter.

Comment: ipconfig is Windows-specific and the OP did not indicate his operating system.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a windows pc your working on you could try ipconfig /flushdns to empty the dns cache